# ListView item write

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I want is writing the in ListView selected item.

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private BenzinCursorAdapter Adapter;

private BenzinDbLoader dbLoader;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         

    dbLoader = new BenzinDbLoader(getApplicationContext());
    dbLoader.open();
    Cursor c = dbLoader.fetchAll();


    Adapter = new BenzinCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), c);
    setListAdapter(Adapter);


    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent,
            View v, int position, long id){
                //Benzin selectedbenzin = (Benzin) parent.getSelectedItem();
        Benzin selectedbenzin = (Benzin) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedbenzin.getDate(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

}
```

The ListView item a Benzin element

```
   public class Benzin {
        private String Date;
        private String Kmo;
        private String Mkm;
        private String Hl;
        private String Mft;
        private String Af;
        private String Osszk;

        public Benzin(String aDate, String aKmo, String aMkm, String aHl,
                String aMft, String aAf, String aOsszk) {
            Date = aDate;
            Kmo = aKmo;
            Mkm = aMkm;
            Hl = aHl;
            Mft = aMft;
            Af = aAf;
            Osszk = aOsszk;

        }

        public String getDate() {
            return Date;
        }

        public String getKmo() {

            return Kmo;
        }


        public String getMkm() {
            return Mkm;
        }


        public String getHl() {
            return Hl;
        }


        public String getMft() {
            return Mft;
    }


    public String getAf() {
        return Af;
    }


    public String getOsszk() {
        return Osszk;
    }

    }
```

I want is writing the in ListView selected item but happens this

Why happened this?

Thanks you

[image]

Comment: Post trace in your log.

Answer (score 0):

Date is a reserved word for Java/Android. Give your variable a different name.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
This good row:
Cursor selectedbenzin = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position);